# Insert, select and update DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a table with time the column named time and the datatype is `Date`.

In asp.net I want a query to insert the date, and another so select between 2 date.

I already try this:

```
string data = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); //date= 28/10/2014 -> dd/mm/yyyy
string comando = "INSERT INTO example (date) values '" +data+ "+"'";
```

And I used that query to select between 2 dates

```
select * 
from example 
where date >= '25/10/2014' and date <= '28/10/2014'
```

I already tried with datatype `varchar` but it doesn't work. So I'm trying with the datatype `date`.

But when I'm executing the query `INSERT` I get a error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Somebody please can help me? The only problem I have is to save the time into the table.

If possible I want that format of the date: `dd/mm/yyyy`

**Update:**

I'm having problem with update a row that have a date(date) and a varchar(name)
That is my code:

```
string comando = "UPDATE example set name=@name WHERE data = @date";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comando, connect);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", nome);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = data;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The messange error is: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: You should follow marc_s's advice by parameterizing your SQL commands. I might be wrong but your SQL looks invalid. It doesn't have any parenthesis around the values. you need... values ('" +data+ "+"')";

Comment: What are the values of `name` and `data`, and what are the definitions of `name` and `data` in your database? Also, `data` is a very bad name for a database column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **NEVER** concatenate together your SQL commands like you do! This opens them up to SQL injection attacks.

Instead - **use parameters!** This also gets rid of a lot of conversion issues.

So in your case, you should use:

```
string comando = "INSERT INTO example (date) VALUES (@DateParam)";
```

and then you need to set the `@DateParam` on your `SqlCommand`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateParam", SqlDbType.Date).Value = YourDataValueHere
```

and that should take care of all your issues!

If you want to select - again, **use parameters!**

```
select * 
from example 
where date >= @fromDate and date <= @toDate
```

when you run this from C#.

If you use T-SQL directly (in Mgmt Studio), then use the **ISO-8601** format `YYYYMMDD` which is indepdent of any dateformat and/or language settings -

```
select * 
from example 
where date >= '20141025' and date <= '20141028'
```

This works on **any** version of SQL Server and with **any** dateformat, language and regional settinsg.

Comment: @youarebeenbannedagain: ***WHAT*** error???? I can't see your screen nor read your mind .....

Comment: "The name 'SqlDbType' does not exist in the current context" and the YourDataValueHere is the this? string data = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

Comment: @youarebeenbannedagain: you need a `using System.Data;` line at the beginning of your code file

Comment: can you help me to update? let me change the question.

Comment: @youarebeenbannedagain: for your `UPDATE` scenario: (1) use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = nome;`; (2) the error says that most likely, the `nome` you're passing it,  is **too long** (longer than what the column in the table is defined as)

Answer (score 1):

If the table really is a `DATE`/`DATETIME`/`DATETIME2`/`SMALLDATETIME`, you'd be better off doing something more like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO example (date) values (@param)"))
{
    cmd.Paramters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = DateTime.Now;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Similarly, when you query the table, something more like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM example WHERE date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate"))
{
    cmd.Paramters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.Paramters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.Datetime).Value = DateTime.Now; // Of course, you'd probably want to pass through values as parameters to your method

    // Fill your dataset/get your SqlDataReader, etc. as preferred
}
```